# How to limit an app to work on an iPhone 5 only?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, app-store, xcode4.5

I googled about it but didn't came to any conclusion.

Can I limit my app to work only for iPhone5 device?

Maybe something like this in .plist file or any other API:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>iPhone5</string>
</array>
```

Anyhow, if this is achievable then can I bypass through app store approval process ? Since up to my knowledge, it may show the MetaData error if I don't upload the screenshots for iPhone4/4S.

So, simply I would like to have my app running on iPhone5 environment only. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to limit it to iPhone 5? (Just to prevent yourself from needing to create other screenshots?) The answer to that question will indicate how you could best do it.

Comment: Actual, the requirement is just for iPhone5 only.Client doesn't want to publish the earlier phones than earlier version of iPhone5.So, anyhow I need to limit the app.Do you find some better approach.

Comment: Well, I don't understand the negative about the question ? Why -2 for this question, neither it has been answered anywhere not the nor some useless things mentioned over here ? Would anybody let me know about the reason for this ?

Answer (score 4):

For iPhone 5 set the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities armv7s (iPhone 5, iPad 4)

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7s</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Note that the app store will reject any app containing only armv7s and not armv7. "Important: The store rejects a binary that supports only armv7s. If armv7s is included in the Valid Architectures list, armv7 must also be included." https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

Answer (score 3):

You could drop support for anything other than armv7s.