# Restricting app installations from AppStore only to users with iPhone 5/5s/5c

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Will adding to the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities "armv7s" and "armv8" restrict users to install my app from AppStore on devices other than iPhone 5/5s/5c?

I have found these articles very useful:

1. [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities and Device Compatibility Matrix](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/10/30/uirequireddevicecapabilities-and-device-compatibility-matrix) (is there any up-to-date info from Apple about device capabilities?)
2. [List of iOS devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#iPhone)

I've also searched all over SO and there was no full/correct answer to my question. Maybe except this one: [Limit the app working on iPhone5 only?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18063696/523630), but it should(?) work only for iPhone 5 and iPhone 5C, not iPhone 5S.

Comment: I have seen many developers indicate the preferred devices in the app description. This is especially prevalent in games. To my knowledge there is no way to restrict installs based on device, only OS version.

Comment: @Dan_Gabicoware, Hm... so, it will be ok to just write about this kind of "restrictions" in app description? Doh... =( not quite what I wanted.

Comment: The more important question is why do you want to restrict your app to those devices only? If it uses a specific sensor for instance. Keep in mind that restricting by CPU may prevent FUTURE devices from using your application as well. Restricting usage of your app is generally a bad idea unless you have a very good, and very specific reason to do so. People with older devices will tolerate reduced performance, and would much rather have the option of running your app. Don't forget, these are your customers as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found this **Important** note:

> The store rejects a binary that supports only armv7s. If armv7s is included in the Valid Architectures list, armv7 must also be included.

From [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW33).

Answer (score 2):

Specifying `armv7s` in your `Info.plist`'s `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` should be enough as it means it requires compatibility with the armv7s instruction set, which in turn is compatible with `arm64` and any future Ax processor.

Also it would be interesting to know why you need to restrict your App in the first place.

---

Up to date Apple capabilities list [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html). There is no official way to cut requirement between iPhone 4 and 5 besides `armv7s`.

Also there is a new good reason to require iPhone 5+ devices: WatchKit apps that have no meaningful iPhone parent app. For instance a game for Apple Watch. One should prevent devices that can not possibly work with the watch from downloading the App.

Comment: Thank you, I'll test this. Why? Hm... I am developing a game, so supporting 3.7 and 4 iPhones is not quite an easy task for our game, even if we are going to use autolayouts etc etc etc.

Comment: AutoLayout has been around since iOS 6.

Comment: You can always launch separate storyboards based off of the device size from the AppDelegate, and not have to deal with autolayout...

Comment: But then you have to deal with maintaining/updating multiple storyboards with very similar contents.

Comment: @jesses.co.tt, thanks... interesting idea about using 2 different storyboard, but... I hate them and the main problem, that we are developing a game which uses a lot of graphics which are localized and contains field sizes (etc) labels with custom effects which can't be done using UILabels.

Comment: @Rivera, nope, this won't work... From Apple: "The store rejects a binary that supports only armv7s. If armv7s is included in the Valid Architectures list, armv7 must also be included."

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](http://9to5mac.com/2015/06/10/ios-9-older-devices-lose-support-apps/comment-page-1/#comment-311294): How to drop support for 4S/5/5S and accomplish what is said in this article without being rejected?

> "The store rejects a binary that supports only armv7s. If armv7s is included in the Valid Architectures list, armv7 must also be included."