# Limiting application to device type?

Tags: iphone, ios7, sprite-kit, frame-rate

When releasing an iPhone application (a game in this case) is there anyway to limit its distribution to only iPhone 5 and above. I know that by using Sprite Kit I automatically limit myself to only iOS7, but I was not sure about the device.

I only ask as the game I am currently writing runs at 60fps on iPhone5/5S but drops to around 40fps in places when running on my iPhone4. I understand I would be loosing customers by doing this but I really want to limit the game to devices where the horse power is available to run the game at full speed.

From my initial research I am assuming this is not possible, but I just wanted to check here before I embark on adding iPhone4 support.

Comment: there isn't a way to limit the app only for iPhone5+ .. but there are many games that only support 4S+ , and simply write in the description of the app that the game is not supported for iPhone4

Comment: Thank you, I might try that, submit it with iPhone4 support (which I believe you currently have to) but then add a note saying "iPhone 5 or above recommended"

Comment: perfect, for now this is the only way ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restricting app installations from AppStore only to users with iPhone 5/5s/5c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878827/restricting-app-installations-from-appstore-only-to-users-with-iphone-5-5s-5c)

Comment: Reading this again: Dropping to 40FPS? I think you're fine on the iPhone 4. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. If your app is already listed on the app store you are pretty much stuck with what you already have.  Changing required device capabilities cannot be done in app updates.
2. I have not read the details on each model but you could use `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` to put limits on what hardware specs needs. There are no entries for screen size but you could, for example, limit your app specs to only use the armv7 and armv8 processors which I believe are present on the iPhone 5, 5c & 5s.

**UPDATE**

Based on additional research and thanks to the comments of Steven Fisher, the answer to the question is that currently no restrictions of the asked type can be made.

Comment: The armv7 is in the iPhone 4 and higher. Requiring iOS 7 would at least require an iPhone 4S.

Comment: @StevenFisher - Ok. What about the armv8?

Comment: I don't think there's a key for that, or at least it isn't documented. But that would limit you to the iPhone 5S (and iPad air/iPad mini 2). There's also armv7s, but there's no key for that (and armv7s only apps are rejected).

Comment: Note: I was wrong earlier. Requiring iOS 7 does not eliminate the original iPhone 4.