# iOS app for specific devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

We are working on a kids app similar to Talking Ben app. It has lots of JPEG image sequences in it for interactive animations.

The thing is the animations are playing fine on iPad Air but they are playing slow or lagging on iPad 2. This is obviously due to the 512 MB RAM in iPad 2.

My question is can we mention in the app description something like - "Recommended devices iPad 3 or later" so that users dont download it on iPad 2 ?
Or can we straight away submit app for only iPad 3 or later devices ?

Whats the legal method for this ?

In short, I want to restrict my app to be downloaded in iPad 2.

Please help guys.

Thanks

Comment: The only way I am aware you can restrict what device an app can be downloaded on is per the iSO version. However this does mean that if a device supports a specific iOS then your app will have to support that in some way. However I have seen app description say that recommended device is whatever. As long as your app runs and doesn't crash then it should make it through the review process.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for replying.... This is what I was thinking that we can mention in the app description that the recommended devices - iPad 3 or later.... 
Can we do this ?
Our app is running fine on all the current devices that apple is selling. So will it bother apple if our app is lagging in its outed or closed devices ?
Thanks

Comment: As long as it still works and is slow to the point of it crashing and it is usable they will pass it.

Comment: Ok.. So the app should work (even lagging) but should not crash for it to get approve.. is it ?

Comment: Yeah as long as it is in a usable state, even if it is lagging. Though to be honest I'd look at alternatives for that device if it is lagging. Maybe look at reducing image quality or remove animation completely from it. Some way so it doesn't lag, reduce quantity is better then it lagging as it will still work for users.

Comment: ok... but for reducing the quality, we will need to add new reduced assests which will increase the overall size of the build... and we cannot remove animations completely as the app is all about tapping and seeing the animals animations...
So I think, I will mention it in the app description that it needs iPad 3 or higher and iPhone 5 or higher to play smooth...

Comment: That's your call all I can do is make recommendations. Good luck with whichever solution you decide to go with.

Comment: Thanks a lot man.. Really appreciate your answers and suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Not too familiar with specifically what architecture is used on the iPad 2, but this post may help you with regards to making sure the app is only compatible with certain architectures: [Restricting app installations from AppStore only to users with iPhone 5/5s/5c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878827/restricting-app-installations-from-appstore-only-to-users-with-iphone-5-5s-5c)

Comment: Hi.. Thanks fo replying... Ill just pass on the above information to my developer as I am a non technical guy...

Can't we just mention in the app description that "Recommended Devices - iPad 3 or later" or something like this so that user get aware of this ?

Comment: Absolutely. If the only issue you have with running your app on an iPad 2 is sluggish performance, that's fine. As long as there are no crashes, Apple should approve the app.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `bluetooth-le` as a requirement in your app `Required device capabilities` in your info.plist.

This should prohibit your app from being installed on iPad 2 as Bluetooth-LE (bluetooth 4.0) is available only since iPad 3rd generation (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad)).

Comment: Hi Nicolas,

Thanks for replying... This seems like a good solution... I'll just paas on this information to my developer...
But cant we mention in our app description something like recommended devices - iPad 3 or later. In this way users can get aware.
Does apple allows this ?

Comment: Doing it this way and not actually using the bluetooth for any functionality will get your app rejected under **2.16** and example of rejection would be `"We found that your app uses a background mode but does not include functionality that requires that mode to run persistently. This behavior is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines. We noticed your app declares support for bluetooth-peripheral in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist, but does not provide Bluetooth Low Energy functionality"` - so this is **Not** the way to go -1

Comment: I think Apple is more touchy with background modes of the app than if it uses bluetooth or not. But that is to check with Apple.

Comment: @NicolasBuquet if you declare that your app is using Bluetooth and it turns out its not then Apple will reject it for declaring Bluetooth and not actually using that functionality. So doing it this way will get your app rejected from the App store.

Comment: I have no experience with this particular situation about bluetooth usage declaration. You can be right.