# Device Requirements (Dropping support for iPhone 4s)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am building a new app and I am toying around with the idea of disallowing iPhone 4s devices from downloading the app. The app just looks horrible on a 4s, and no amount of auto-layout magic will make it look better without completely redesigning the UI.

I've looked over the [Device Requirements document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) and a site called the [iOS Compatibility Calculator](http://28byteslater.com/ios-compatibility/?exclude=10&require=9#chart). I discovered that I can exclude the iPhone 4s device by enforcing a minimum requirement of the armv7s chip. Unfortunately, when attempting to change the architecture key on my target, the application still compiles on an iPhone 4s simulator.

TL;DR: Does anybody know how to properly achieve iPhone5+ compatibility by setting the armv7s minimum requirement?

Comment: Maybe not a good idea, might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23199645/600753

Comment: I'll test it out, and push to test flight and see what happens!

Comment: Please do let us know what happens, I'm in the same position of wanting to eliminate 4S.

Comment: Will do! Thankfully, we still have an iPhone 4s device somewhere to test on.

Comment: Doesn't work :( http://imgur.com/3PP8u5w