# How to drop support for iPhone 5S

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I want to release my app to the Appstore, and only allow users using an iPhone 6 and above to download the app.

I was hoping that requiring ARKit or iOS 11 would be able to drop support for 5S and below, but unfortunately 5S can run both.

My requirement is that I need support for 60 fps video recording at 1080p.

Can anyone think of a requirement that will allow me to drop 5S support?

Answer (score 2):

According to the below Apple document, the iPhone 5S does not support `ARKit`, so limiting to `ARKit` only devices should be the solution you are looking for.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html

Comment: the iPhone 6 & 6+ do not support `ARKit` either.  Wow!  They really obsolete devices & functionality a little too quickly, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in your project. You can write condition based on the Device type to exclude the divices you don't want to run.

```
struct ScreenSize {
    static let SCREEN_WIDTH         = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    static let SCREEN_HEIGHT        = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH    = max(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH    = min(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    static let WIDTH_RATIO          = ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH / 320
    static let HEIGHT_RATIO         = ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 568
}

struct DeviceType {
    static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS  = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_5          = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6          = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6P         = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
    static let IS_IPAD              = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH >= 1024.0
}
```

Comment: This won't prevent users from actually downloading the app from the app store though right?

Comment: Specifying armv7s in your Info.plist's UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities should be enough as it means it requires compatibility with the armv7s instruction set, which in turn is compatible with arm64 and any future Ax processor.     refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878827/restricting-app-installations-from-appstore-only-to-users-with-iphone-5-5s-5c

Comment: If I am not mistaken armv7s is supported as far back as iPhone 5?